# Java: How to bind values from two different arrays

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a list of usernames and one of nodes. I need a data structure to hold information about what usernames are on a given node. I would need something like `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>` but I also need to perform operation on the whole username list in an easy (not on a bunch of different arrays). Does that data structure exists or I need to hold two`ArrayList` and an `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>` seems like a reasonable solution to me. I don't see any need for custom structures here.

For the operations with usernames, you can use `.keySet()` or `.entrySet()` (or any method of iteration).

See [How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898/1253136).

Answer (score 1):

I like your original thought about using a `Map`.  I think a `Map` would be a good start for this problem.

Are all the usernames guaranteed to be unique?  If so, I would use a `Set` instead of a `List` to represent the usernames.  Maybe you could first transfer all usernames in the list to a `Set<Usernames>`, then you could iterate through the node/username lists to generate your `Map<Node, Set<Usernames>>`.

You would to keep track of the `Set<Usernames>` and a `Map<Node, Set<Usernames>>`, but I think it would store the right data and you could do fast lookup operations on the username set.

Answer (score 0):

If something doesn't exist in Java you can try to create on your own:

**Node**:

```
public class Node {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**User**:

```
public class User {
    String username;
    String name;
    String surname;
    // ...
}
```

You can just use `List<String> usernames` in your `Node`, if you don't need a complex object.

Then, somewhere in your app:

```
public List<User> getUsersOfNode(Node node) {
    return node.getUsers();
}
```

Operating with this is easier than with `HashMap`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create an object for that, with 3 private fields (two lists and one map)?